# Outlook mail item last modification time not getting updated C#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have an outlook add in with C#.

I am updating the data in database with the dates when we drag and drop in particular folder .

Ex :  If I drag to from sent items to xxx folder then I am updating that date.

In my system it is updating properly but when I create setup file and install it on other system it is not getting latest time.

```
items.LastModificationTime.ToUniversalTime()
```

By using above code I am getting time which is not updating.

In this items is the mail item of `MAPIFolder`

for example in I am system if drag the email into XXX folder it is capturing the dragged time, but in other system it is showing the sent time only as lastmodified time rather than current action time.

Does it depends on server?

Comment: Does it get updated after you restart Outlook?

Comment: No every time on restart also I am getting the same time. Basically I need email dragged time into other folders.